# Google Cloud build python not found when trigger is running

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I'm a software developer and new to GCP. Yesterday I was trying to deploy a simple Spring Boot Application to the App Engine using this tutorial https://medium.com/google-cloud/gcp-deploying-to-app-engine-from-github-using-cloud-build-df2582f968.... I didn't use his code, as I allready have my project set up on Github. It's a simple hello world application.

After pushing a new commit to github, the build is running, but it gets an error

```
INFO: Downloading https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/google-cloud-  sdk.tar.gz to /root/.cache/google-cloud-tools-java/managed-cloud-sdk/downloads/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
Welcome to the Google Cloud CLI!
WARNING: You appear to be running this script as root. This may cause the installation to be inaccessible to users other than the root user.
/root/.cache/google-cloud-tools-java/managed-cloud-sdk/LATEST/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh: line 221: python: not found
```

Here is my cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
   - name: maven:3-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine
     entrypoint: mvn
     args: [ "test" ]
   - name: maven:3-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine
     entrypoint: mvn
     args: [ "package", "-Dmaven.test.skip=true","appengine:deploy" ]
   - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
     args: [ "build", "-t", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/backend", "--build-arg=JAR_FILE=target/backend-0.0.1.jar", "." ]
   images: [ "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/backend" ]
```

Comment: It seems that gcloud SDK is installed in the `root` directory. Try [uninstalling the Google Cloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/uninstall-cloud-sdk) then [install the gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install)  in your `home` directory so that it would see the service account and libraries it needs to deploy your projects.

Comment: I didn't install it, it is installed trough cloud build.

Comment: Have you tried following this documentation on [building and pushing a Docker image with Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-push-docker-image) instead so that the Docker repo is created using Artifact Registry instead of Github?